# Run HQL file in Spark and pass parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to read an HQL file with multiple SQL statements that might have some variables. For example:

```
select * from table
where ds = '$ds';

select * from table2
where ds > '$ds1' and ds < '$ds2';
```

I know how to read and parse the file. How do I pass variables from Scala code into the string that I will read from the file?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've found a solution for my problem posted above. It's not ideal what I was thinking to do but on the end it works for me. 
I will pass those arguments with SET statements like below:

```
set ds="2018-05-20";

select * from table
where ds = ${ds};
```